# "Return" in Function only Returning one Value

Tags: python, function, for-loop, printing, return

Let's say I write a for loop that will output all the numbers 1 to x:

```
x=4
for number in xrange(1,x+1):
    print number,
#Output:
1
2
3
4
```

Now, putting that same for loop into a function:

```
def counter(x):
    for number in xrange(1,x+1):
        return number
print counter(4)
#Output:
1
```

Why do I only obtain one value when I put the for-loop into a function?

I have been evading this problem by appending all the results of the for-loop to a list, and then returning the list.

Why does the for loop append all the results, and not just one?:

```
def counter(x):
    output=[]
    for number in xrange(1,x+1):
        output.append(number)
    return output
```

What is the best method of returning all the values, appending to a list seems very inefficient.

Comment: `return` returns from a function.  You may be interested in `yield` but that will require learning what `return` does in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`return` does exactly like the keyword's name implies.  When you hit that statement, it *returns* and the rest of the function is not executed.

What you might want instead is the `yield` keyword.  This will create a generator function (a function that returns a generator).  Generators are iterable.  They "yield" one element each time the `yield` expression is executed.

```
def func():
    for x in range(10):
        yield x

generator = func()
for item in generator:
    print item
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want is is called a **Generator**:

```
def counter(x):
    for number in xrange(1,x+1):
        yield number
```

You would then use it like this:

```
c = counter(5)
next(c)  # 1
next(c)  # 2
```

You could also consume the entire *generator* by doing:

```
xs = list(c)  # xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

See: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators for more information.

The **return** statement in Python returns form the function and does not save any state. Every time you call the function a new stack frame is created. **yield** on the other hand is (*more or less*) Python's equivilent of [continutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation)

Answer (score 2):

Once `return` in a function, the function ends and the remaining code won't be excuted any more.
Your second solution is good and if you want better solution, you can use generator:

```
def counter(x):
    for number in xrange(1,x+1):
        yield number
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
>>> for i in counter(5):
...     print i
... 
1
2
3
4
5
```