# Beginner python game: Craps, while-loop issue

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to programming and my assignment is to make a craps game. The game keeps going until you reply "no" when asked to play again. Once you enter "no" it is supposed to show how many times you won and lost. It worked fine with this (not keeping score):

```
import random

def main():

    playGame = input("Would you like to play Craps? (Enter yes or no): ")
    while playGame == 'yes':
        roll = input("Press Enter to roll the dice")
        rollDice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        rollDice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("You got a", rollDice1, "and a", rollDice2)
        rolledDice = rollDice1 + rollDice2
        print("you rolled a", rolledDice)
        if rolledDice == 7 or rolledDice == 11:
            print("IT'S YOUR LUCKY DAY! YOU WIN!")

        elif rolledDice == 2 or rolledDice == 3 or rolledDice == 12:
            print("YOU LOSE! BETTER LUCK NEXT TIME!")

        else:
            print("YOU NEITHER WIN NOR LOSE!")

        playGame = input("Try again? (Enter yes or no): ")
        if playGame == "no":
            print("Place holder")
main()
```

When I tried to keep score and it wouldn't loop when you win or lose. (Though it still loops when you don't win nor lose):

```
import random

def main():
    wins = 0
    losses = 0

    playGame = input("Would you like to play Craps? (Enter yes or no): ")
    while playGame == 'yes':
        roll = input("Press Enter to roll the dice")
        rollDice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        rollDice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("You got a", rollDice1, "and a", rollDice2)
        rolledDice = rollDice1 + rollDice2
        print("you rolled a", rolledDice)
        if rolledDice == 7 or rolledDice == 11:
            print("IT'S YOUR LUCKY DAY! YOU WIN!")
            wins = wins + 1
            return wins

        elif rolledDice == 2 or rolledDice == 3 or rolledDice == 12:
            print("YOU LOSE! BETTER LUCK NEXT TIME!")
            losses = losses + 1
            return losses

        else:
            print("YOU NEITHER WIN NOR LOSE!")

        playGame = input("Try again? (Enter yes or no): ")
        if playGame == "no":
            print("Wins: ", wins)
            print("Losses: ", losses)
main()
```

I appreciate any help and advice given. Like I said I'm new to this, so please try to explain what's wrong and what I should do in a simple way.

Comment: Don't use strings a boolean values. Python knows `True` and `False`.

Comment: If you `return` - you leave the function - your game is over. Delete those rows and it will work.

Comment: Very similar - if not a dupe: [return-in-function-only-returning-one-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604773/return-in-function-only-returning-one-value)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Did not know return leaves the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `return` something from inside a function you leave it - thats why your while loop does not work:

> ```
> def main():
>     wins = 0
>     losses = 0
>
>     playGame = input("Would you like to play Craps? (Enter yes or no): ")
>     while playGame == 'yes':
>         roll = input("Press Enter to roll the dice")
>         rollDice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
>         rollDice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
>         print("You got a", rollDice1, "and a", rollDice2)
>         rolledDice = rollDice1 + rollDice2
>         print("you rolled a", rolledDice)
>         if rolledDice == 7 or rolledDice == 11:
>             print("IT'S YOUR LUCKY DAY! YOU WIN!")
>             wins = wins + 1
>             return wins   # EXITS main() - simply delete this row
>
>         elif rolledDice == 2 or rolledDice == 3 or rolledDice == 12:
>             print("YOU LOSE! BETTER LUCK NEXT TIME!")
>             losses = losses + 1
>             return losses # EXITS main() - simply delete this row
>
>         else:
>             print("YOU NEITHER WIN NOR LOSE!")
>
>         playGame = input("Try again? (Enter yes or no): ")
>         if playGame == "no":
>             print("Wins: ", wins)
>             print("Losses: ", losses)
> ```

```
             return  # add this to exit the function (could use break as well)
```

> ```
> main()
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I removed return and it loops again.